# QMainWindow fullscreen issue due to taskbar on windows

Tags: windows, qt, qwidget, qmainwindow

I am trying to make a fullscreen window (not just maximized one).

```
QMainWindow *mainWindow;
mainWindow->showFullScreen();
```

This works fine on Linux (tested on Ubuntu 16) and on windows(working on Windows 10) if taskbar is set to auto hide. If taskbar is not set to auto hide a white rectangular strip appears in place of taskbar in fullscreen mode. I assumed that a fullscreen window should be able to hide the taskbar but it's not happening in this case.

I have already tried following workarounds but none of them is working for me:

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, mainWindow, SLOT(showFullScreen()));

mainWindow->setWindowState(mainWindow->windowState() ^ Qt::WindowFullScreen);

mainWindow->setWindowState(mainWindow->windowState() & ~Qt::WindowFullScreen);

mainWindow->repaint();

qApp->processEvents();

mainWindow->setGeometry(qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry());
mainWindow->updateGeometry();
```

Is there any other method to make a QMainWindow/QWidget fullscreen or I need to hide the taskbar explicitly?

Comment: I tried **mainWindow->showFullScreen();** it is working as you desire. It covers all area including taskbar on windows 10.

Comment: @Sourabh It's not working for me in case when taskbar is not set to autohide. A white strip appears in place of taskbar at the bottom.

Comment: I'm having this problem too.  `mainWindow->showFullScreen()` doesn't make the application render over the taskbar.  Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Nevermind, I had to restart explorer.exe using Task Manager and now it works correctly.